# Selecting the maximum based off the last FALSE boolean value [T-SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to pull the last record by most current EndDate that IsOpen = FALSE"

```
WeekID   |      EndDate     |    IsOpen   |  TransmitDate  |

 1             2015-03-14         False      2015-03-15
 2             2015-03-20         False      2015-03-21
 3             2015-03-26         True       2015-03-27
 4             2015-04-02         True       2015-04-03
```

In this case, I am looking to get the WeekID, EndDate, IsOpen, TransmitDate
but only show the LAST row that has a false instead of all of them with a false value. In this case

```
WeekID   |      EndDate     |    IsOpen   |  TransmitDate  |
 2             2015-03-20         False      2015-03-21
```

I have tried casting the boolean value of IsOpen as an integer but my logic is a little faulty as to how to get it to show what I need.

```
SELECT  WeekID, EndDate, IsOpen, TransmitDate FROM dbo.Weeks WHERE IsOpen = (SELECT max(cast(IsOpen as int)) FROM dbo.Weeks)
```

From what I have tried so far this will only return all the True values.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you call your column `isOpen` and `Open`, what is the correct name?

Comment: Do the dates not matter in determining order?  I.E. a record could be later in the table but earlier than a previous record.  What is the purpose of pulling the last possible `IsOpen = FALSE` record?

Comment: Forgive me, that is meant to be IsOpen

Comment: Last according the primary key or the date column?

Comment: The order of the dates does matter. As I need the last EndDate possible based off of the last one that has a IsOpen value of False.

Comment: Are you looking for the max Enddate? or WeekID? or Transmit Date? i.e how do you want to `ORDER` the results before getting the `TOP` 1? And that's what you will need to do SELECT TOP 1 FROM yourTable WHERE IsOpen is false and order by your desired column.

Comment: @FredyTeyssedou: so if there was another record with `EndDate=2015-04-03` and `IsOpen = 0`, then you want that? So always the very last record? Then it's simple and ASh has already answered it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am looking for the Max EndDate and TransmitDate based off of the last entry in IsOpen that is False

Comment: You should rephrase the question to "I would like to pull the last record by most current EndDate that `IsOpen = FALSE`" then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top 1` in combination with `order by` will return the last row

```
SELECT top 1 WeekID, EndDate, [Open], TransmitDate
FROM dbo.Weeks 
WHERE [Open] = 0
order by EndDate desc
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a boolean type in SQL Server. You want to compare the column with true/false to a  varchar 'true' or 'false'

Comment: Well, no boolean, but there's a bit datatype, so

Comment: As far as I know you cannot compare a bit to true/false unless you do things like case or IIF.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits - See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) for true/false handling of bit data. Example: `declare @Foo as bit = 1; select case @Foo when 'True' then 'Yea' when 'False' then 'Nay' end;`. Similarly, `where IsOpen = 'False'`.

Comment: That's my whole point. You cannot handle true/false directly. See my previous comment.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits - Can you elaborate on _directly_? `declare @Foo as bit = 1; select 42 where @Foo = 'True';` strikes me as not overly convoluted. No `CASE` or `IIF` needed, as I mentioned in my example `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The questionaire said 'I have tried casting the boolean value of IsOpen as an integer but my logic ..' and I pointed out there is no boolean type in SQL Server. In my response I pointed out that you can compare it to 'true' or 'false' (treating it as the varchar that it is). I am not sure what we disagree about.